# Set the location of the tempdir

Tags: .htaccess

It is probarly pretty simple, but i cant find an solution.

How can i set the temp dir for file uploads.

What i want is change the location to www.mydomain.com/temporary

what i have tryd in .htaccess

```
 php_value upload_tmp_dir "/home/mydomain.com/public_html/temporary/"
```

and without the last slash.

```
  php_value upload_tmp_dir "/home/mydomain.com/public_html/temporary"
```

Does some one know if it is done by .htaccess and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), `upload_tmp_dir` can be changed only in php.in, not on a per-directory basis:

```
upload_tmp_dir  NULL    PHP_INI_SYSTEM
```

You'd have to have root access to the server to change that.

Comment: not with php-fpm